# Radio button doesnt appear on my default DjangoModelform. I cant find the issue?

Tags: python, django, object, url, view

[image]This is my model where I want my Gender field to appear as radio button.

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    # book_id = models.OneToOneField(Booking,
    #       on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Nationality = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_No = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_Exp_Date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    Contact_Number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

This is my template.

```
    <form  method="POST">
                                                                                    
       {% csrf_token %}
                                                                                    
      {{ form|crispy }}                                                                                                                                                             
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction="{% url 'addcustomer' %}">Submit</button>
                                                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="{% url 'customerlist' %}">Cancel</button>
                                                                            </form>
```

This is my Passenger form.

```
class PassengerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Passport_Exp_Date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Others')]
    Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model= Passenger
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can u show the screenshot of the form that is being rendered?

Comment: Ok, I have posted it. please check it.

Comment: Also, show your template.

Comment: yes i have shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify it in your html template as

```
<input type="radio" value="your-form-instance.Gender" />
```

Comment: I dont have the custom form. I have deafult django ModelForm. I will post it in the question. please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CHOICES = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')]
Gender=forms.CharField(label='Gender', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I did according to your code but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', Male),
   ('F', 'Female'),('O', 'Others'),
 )
class Passenger(models.Model):
    # book_id = models.OneToOneField(Booking,
    #       on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Nationality = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_No = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_Exp_Date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    Contact_Number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)


class PassengerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Passport_Exp_Date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model= Passenger
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
               'Gender': forms.RadioSelect()
           }
```